# Elastic search query criteria for multiple ids

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using elastic search to index around 3 million products. The products are grouped as family, buckets etc. When we index the products we include their family, bucketid so that when the user is able to search the products they can use this familyid, bucketid etc. Everything works fine until this.

Right now there is one more additional requirement where the user after searching by familyId and bucketId will download the complete list of productIds(this might be about 50k records). Then manually delete few productIds and add few productIds and then upload the same in our system. Now, the expectation is the system should search for this 50k records. The straightforward approach I can think of is pass these 50k ids as search value and get the products. Does this sound reasonable ? Is there any better solution like creating a dynamic classification in elastic search with this new group ?

Comment: Would it be conceivable to compute the ID of your documents as a function of the familyid, bucketid and productid?

Comment: The problem is when the user uploads the excel with the productids there is no predefined classification. The user can choose to add products from a completely different family too

Comment: If I'm correct, you trying to update your indexed documents (delete some documents, add some documents, etc..)
one approach is to actually update and delete using the API for update and delete.
second approach, which can be more straightforward is to re-index the updated 50K records to a new index. this approach can give you the classification you need

Comment: No, we arent updating the document. we are letting the user search on productId by giving a list of productids in an excel